# Loop and make new instance object every iteration c#

Tags: c#

so I am trying to make a loop in which I create a new instance of an object every time it loops: something like this.

```
Client client = new Client(session);
client.Connect(server);

while (true) {
    client.SendPacket(new Craft.Net.CreativeInventoryActionPacket(-1, new Craft.Net.ItemStack((short)19, (sbyte)1)));

    client.Disconnect ("Generic");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

    //obviously I cannot do this, because there is already an object named client.
    Client client = new Client(session);

    client.Connect(server);
}
```

How would I go about doing this? I need to make a NEW instance of MinecraftClient, I cannot reuse the old one after I do client.Disconnect.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing that works is to change

```
Client client = new Client(session);
```

to

```
client = new Client(session);
```

That said, I think there's a cleaner approach. Start with:

```
while(true) {
    Client client = new Client(session);
    client.Connect(server);
    client.SendPacket (new Craft.Net.CreativeInventoryActionPacket(-1, new Craft.Net.ItemStack((short)19, (sbyte)1)));
    client.Disconnect ("Generic");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Now factor that out into a method:

```
private void ConnectAndDoStuff() {
    Client client = new Client(session);
    client.Connect(server);
    client.SendPacket (new Craft.Net.CreativeInventoryActionPacket(-1, new Craft.Net.ItemStack((short)19, (sbyte)1)));
    client.Disconnect ("Generic");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); 
}
```

And then:

```
while(true) { this.ConnectAndDoStuff() }
```

Comment: +1, but of course you need a way to break out of the while loop, which I presume is being handled separately?

Comment: I'm not sure that factoring out a 5-line method (that presumably has one caller) is ipso facto an improvement.

Comment: @KirkWoll Actually, it's a great improvement. The number of lines are irrelevant, I'd probably split it even more -> One method for connecting and one for `DoingStuff`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, I don't think splitting functionality because of the ability to name discrete ideas necessarily outweighs the cost of obscuring the implementation of the logic.

Comment: @KirkWoll Not sure exactly what you mean, but if *anything* encapsulating the implementation in a method (preferably smaller methods) increases the readability and maintainability of the code. That's just in principle, not necessary in this particular scenario. Also I should include a big "IMHO" somewhere there.

Comment: @KirkWoll Also I think I should add that I have strong opinions about this because of my previous experiences with 500 lines methods/routines/procedures with useless comments sprinkled all over the place that make me want to shoot myself, but you know, that's just me :)

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, your point presumes that method names are more readable than code.  I would argue that well-written code is already readable; no need to hide the implementation with english descriptions of what is already readily apparent to anyone fluent in the language.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I think that this attitude brings us to the 500 lines monsters that I had to tackle on many occasions, because the 1337 h4x0r thought it's pretty obvious what he was doing :) Let's just agree to disagree, maybe you just had different experience than I did, or maybe you're just much smarter than I am (which is not a big achievement since I'm not so bright :D), cheers

Comment: Dimitar, Right, you went from 5 lines to 500 lines in your imaginary problem.  Hope you enjoy your debate with the strawman.

Comment: @KirkWoll Well, look I'm just trying to say that (IMHO) generally smaller clearer methods with good names are better than 1 method no matter which way you look at it, whether is 5 lines or 15, 50 or 500 (especially 500!), it comes as a surprise to me that people don't agree, honestly

Comment: Anyway, I see your point, not trying to convince you, not debating, I might not be right, it's just my opinion. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Create the instance in the loop every time you start again.

```
while (true) {
    Client client = new Client(session);
    client.Connect(server);
    client.SendPacket (new Craft.Net.CreativeInventoryActionPacket(-1, new Craft.Net.ItemStack((short)19, (sbyte)1)));
    client.Disconnect ("Generic");

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to recreate the `client` object just remove the Type definition

```
    Client client = new Client(session);
    client.Connect(server);
    while (true)
    {
        client.SendPacket (new Craft.Net.CreativeInventoryActionPacket(-1, new Craft.Net.ItemStack((short)19, (sbyte)1)));
        client.Disconnect ("Generic");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        client = new Client(session); 
        client.Connect(server);
    }
```